# Cast double to Int64 in C# causing problems on mobile device?

Tags: ios, mobile, casting, double, int64

I've got some code for a game I'm working on that converts double values to Int64. The problem areas is as follows:

```
double xVal = 1.6;    

Int64 xValInt64 = (Int64)xVal;
Int32 xValInt32 = (Int32)xVal;
```

Testing on my PC works great.

However, testing on my mobile device (iPhone) results in:

```
xValInt64 = 4609884575999459329
xValInt32 = 1
```

I can't wrap my mind around why this is happening. Anybody dealt with this before? Why is my cast not working?

Comment: Can you show a *complete* (self-contained) example, with the double input, the Int64 output and the expected output?

Comment: Your question might benefit from specifying what language/SDK you're working with.

Comment: Okay, I've amended the title and example code to better explain the problem.

Comment: How are you using C# on an iPhone?

Comment: I don't know the exactly compilation process, but the C# code is given to Unity Engine, which builds an Xcode project which is then executed on the device.

Comment: How/where is `Int64` defined?

Comment: The xValInt64 value, treated as a bit pattern and interpreted as double, is 1.5999994277954103782946049250313080847263336181640625. This is close to 1.6, but not close enough to be the value of a double 1.6 literal.